# Javascript issue making a stopwatch?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Currently I am working on making a stopwatch in html with javascript(jquery to be exact).

```
<body>
    <div class="background">
        <div class="stopwatch-background">
            <div class="boxes">
                <div class="border" id="minuteText"></div>
                <div class="big-semicolon">:</div>
                <div class="border" id="secondText"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="button-holder">
                <button class="btn btn-primary" id="start">Start</button>
                <button class="btn btn-primary" id="pause">Pause</button>
                <button class="btn btn-primary" id="reset">Reset</button>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript" >
        var start = false;
        var minuteHand = 30;
        var secondHand = 60;
        function setDefault(){
            minuteHand = 30;
            secondHand = 60;
        }
        function DecreaseValue() {
            if (start) {
                UpdateText();
                if (minuteHand >= 1) {
                    if (secondHand >= 1) {
                        secondHand--;
                    } else if (secondHand == 0) {
                        minuteHand--;
                        secondHand = 60;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        function UpdateText() {
            $("#minuteText").html = minuteHand;
            $("#secondText").html = secondText;
        }
        $("#start").click(function () {
            start = true;
        });
        $("#pause").click(function () {
            start = false;
        });
        $("#reset").click(function () {
            setDefault();
            start = false;
        });
        setInterval(DecreaseValue, 1000);
    </script>

</body>
```

The problem is$("#start").html is not changing any content. And I am also not sure whether my other code works or not. Please help me. I have not posted any css.

Comment: Does your `DecreaseValue ` function gets called?

Comment: setInterval calls it right

Comment: html is a method.... `$("#minuteText").html(minuteHand);` and it is secondHand, not secondText

Comment: Try to debug it using `console.log` and see if all your `if` blocks are executed or not.

Answer (score 2):

The jquery syntax for setting the html content is like below,

```
function UpdateText() {
            $("#minuteText").html(minuteHand);
            $("#secondText").html(secondHand);
        }
```

.html is a method and the value should be passed as an argument to it. Take a look at the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/html/). Also you need to set secondHand as the html content instead of secondText.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
        $("#minuteText").html(minuteHand+"");
        $("#secondText").html(secondHand+"");
```